# Fake actionEvent doesn't dispose window. (Password dialog box)

Tags: java, passwords

I am using JOptionPane confirm dialog for password entry, it has OK and Cancel buttons and when I am using a while loop to detect when correct password has been entered, when user presses Cancel or "X", I trigger fake actionEvent to dispose window using this.dispose(); but for some weird reason it doesn't work and window opens regardless.

Here is the code:

```
while(identifier<1) {
  if(action == 0) {
    if(Arrays.equals(password.getPassword(),pass)) {
      break;
    } else {
      actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(2,-1,""));
      break;
    }
  } else {
    actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(2,-1,"");
    break;
  }
}
```

And here is the part from actionPerformed method which should close the window:

```
if(e.getSource()==2) {
  this.dispose();
}
```

Comment: java.util.EventObject.getSource() returns an Object...e.getSource()==2 doesn't look right to me...try outputting e.getSource() to see what it's returning

Comment: Why is this in a while loop?  Every case has a break statement.

Comment: Because I am using it to detect OK/CANCEL from the confirm dialog box, and now I have sorted it out by carefully debugging each line, I found out that the problem was that it was trying to dispose of the window BEFORE it was actually initialized. So I have moved whole while statement under the the line which makes window visible and now it works just as I wanted. Thank you, and sorry.

Comment: This all sound every scary. It sound like your manipulating UI components out side the Event Dispatching Thread, which is a very bad idea